# id not going through the url

Tags: php, mysql

my id is not going through the url. my code is as follows

```
    <?php
include 'library/connect.php';

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM meetings ");

echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Title</th><th>Chairman</th><th>Secretary</th><th>Terms of Reference</th><th>Named membership</th><th>Occurences</th><th>Book Room</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['title']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['chairman']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['secretary']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['termsOfReference']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['named_membership']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['occurences']. "</td>";

        ?>
    <td><a href ="secretary_booksRoom.php?meeting_id=<?php echo $meeting_id; ?>"><font color="#CC3300">Book: room/date/time</font></a></td>

<?php
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
include 'library/closedb.php';
?>
```

have you got any idea of what the problem can be?

Comment: Close your tr inside the look, not outside.

Comment: I can't see where you define  $meeting_id;

Comment: Are u sure u have put the declared the value of $meeting_id?? because its not there in the above code..

Comment: It will be easier to point out if you explain the purpose of code a bit, i.e. what u wish to do

Comment: @PrashantSingh well, the code intention looks pretty clear..and the error too, imho

Answer (score 1):

where is `$meeting_id` set? seems to me like it should be `$row['meeting_id']`.

Answer (score 1):

Where `$meeting_id` is defined?
It seems like you did a select but forgot to retrieve the meeting id.

Try to change the link to:

```
<a href ="secretary_booksRoom.php?meeting_id=<?php echo $row['meeting_id']; ?>">
```

In case you have column named `meeting_id` in your table of course.

Answer (score 0):

`<tr>` tag need to be closed in the while loop

Comment: although true, how does this affect the link?

Comment: Still that doesn't print the content of $meeting_id, though :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the $meeting_id variable before adding it to the URL, otherwise your link will simply be "secretary_booksRoom.php?meeting_id=". I am going to assume that your meetings table has an id column as a primary key. In your while loop, try declaring "$meetind_id = $row['your meeting id column']". This should get the meeting id and pass it to the URL.

Hope this helps.